# How do I reuse a map in multiple divs in Cordova Google Maps plugin?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm aware that the [plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) throws a singleton map. But what I want to do is use the same map for two different views in my ionic project. I want to clear the map when the user switches between the views to make it appear like a new map.

I tried the following :

```
    //one way
    var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap() 

    map.setDiv('map_canvas1')  
    map.setDiv('map_canvas2')



   //other way
   .controller('ExploreCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById('map_canvas1')
            var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div)
        })

    })
    .controller('GeofenceCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById('map_canvas2')
            var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div)

        })
    })
```

but was unable to achieve the functionality. The map displays only on one div, whichever tab I click first, in the later code snippet. Is it something that's possible ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, have you a solution to clear map ? i have the some probleme with ionic angularJS platform :(

Comment: Hi. I have a same issue with ionic 1. Have you found a solution to use the plugin with different divs? Thanks!